# Problem executing in linux command

Tags: linux, awk

I'm executing a Linux command and executing from an automated script.

```
ps | awk '/dspload -d 1 -e/&&!/awk/{print $1}'
```

Now when I see the logs of the script and look at the location where it gets executed I see something like this

```
root@dm365-evm:/usr/share/ti/dvtb# ps | awk '/dspload -d 1 -e/&&!/awk/{print $1}'
```

That causes command not to run properly.

Could anyone suggest how I can run it like:

```
root@dm365-evm:/usr/share/ti/dvtb# ps | awk '/dspload -d 1 -e/&&!/awk/{print $1}'
```

Comment: What does "not to run properly" mean? The expected output is not clear from this description of the problem.

Comment: Johnsyweb from automated script command is running like this

Comment: $1}' is getting into next line an di don't want it to go in new line

Comment: is this question deserve to be got negtive vote...i don't like it

Comment: @AMIT: and the expected output is…

Comment: still i couldn't make it work

Comment: my automated script just hang there

Comment: Please explain what output you get from the command, and what output you would *like* to get. Like this the question is pointless. Voting to close.

Comment: @AMIT: The question is currently very vague and downvotes should be expected until it is clarified.

Answer (score 1):

Given the comments after the question, are you sure the text editor you are using to write the script isn't adding newlines (word wrapping) into your command?  I.e., does your script file contain a newline within the argument to `awk`?

Comment: no i am sure text editor is not adding new line

Comment: one of the possiblty i would imagine is command doesn't have enough time to be written on prompt

Comment: @AMIT: How do you know that the command is being split into two lines?  How are you running it in your script?

Comment: In logs i can command gets splited and this how am running script

Comment: cmd = "ps | awk '/#{process}/ && !/awk/ {print $1}'"
      output = board.send_puts(cmd, @target_prompt) where @target_prompt is  :/usr/share/ti/dvtb

Comment: @AMIT: In that case, try to escape `$1` like jk suggests.  Or did you try that already?

Comment: i tried but could make it work i tried to run like cmd = "ps | awk '/#{process}/ && !/awk/ {print \$1}' is it the right way??

Comment: @AMIT: Can you try printing out `cmd` just before you try to use it?  That might help to find out if it's getting corrupted somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to escape the dollar sign, e.g. \$1.

Comment: thanks jk for ur response u want to say i should run this command like  ps | awk '/dspload -d 1 -e/&&!/awk/{print \$1}'

Comment: yes, try that and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this has been migrated from StackOverflow, as the question is as unclear here as it is there.

It *looks* like you are trying to get a list of PIDs of all running processes matching "`dspload -d 1 -e`" but excluding `awk` (which you are using to filter the output of `ps` and just grab the first column.

It also *looks* like your command, `ps | awk '/dspload -d 1 -e/&&!/awk/{print $1}'` is working from the command-line. On whichever operating system you are running, within whichever shell you are running. I *suspect* that the output looks something like:

```
23875
23874
1368
23873
```

I gather that rather than try to remember this complicated command-line, you have put it into some kind of file and are trying to run it as a shell-script but this is not working. I have no idea what this shell script looks like.

I can tell you that if your shell script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
ps | awk '/dspload -d 1 -e/&&!/awk/{print $1}'
```

Then running it will give you the same output as running the command at a bash prompt on Mac OS X.

If you have you have extracted the process to a variable, you'll need to ensure that this is is expanded within the call to `awk`, *viz*:

```
#!/bin/sh
process="dspload -d 1 -e"
ps | awk '/'${process}'/&&!/awk/{print $1}'
```

Using single quotes (`'`) will mean that `$1`, which has a special meaning within the Bourne Shell, will not be expanded (but will be interpreted by `awk`.

Any decent editor will highlight the syntax for you and help you to spot any errors.

Comment: thanks Johnsweb for ur wonderfull response ... my question is quite simple when i tried to run this commnad                                                                   ps | awk '/dspload -d 1 -e/&&!/awk/{print $1}'
on prompt what i see is > sign even if tried to run                                                                    ps | awk '/top -b -d 1/ && !/awk/ {print $1}

got same thing ..i don't why people not able to get it .....